# Find the area between the graphs of two functions involving exponentials

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, area

> Let the function $f:\Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ and $g:\Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ be defined by
> $$f(x)=e^{x-1}-e^{-|x-1|}$$
> and
> $$g(x)=\frac{1}{2}(e^{x-1}+e^{1-x}).$$
> Then find the area of the region in the first quadrant bounded by the curves $y=f(x)$,$y=g(x)$ and $x=0$.

*My attempt*: The graphs of $y=f(x)$ and $y=g(x)$ intersect at a point where $x=1+\ln \sqrt{3}$. So the region in the first quadrant between these two graphs split into two parts, that where $0$ to $1$ and $1$ to $1+\ln \sqrt{3}$.

*My doubt*: Any short method for this problem.Actually the work demand is too long as it has four parts ,to idntify the region .

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE. I've tried to format your question for you. I had to make an educated guess about some of the exponents, so please check to make sure that the question is as you intended. I'm also not really sure what the final sentence means, so you might want to elaborate.

Comment: @Theo: thanks for editing my question .

Comment: No problem! If you like the site, you should probably consider trying to learn how to format your own questions. See our [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for a quick reference. You can also press "edit" to see how I've formatted your question. You can even play around with the code to see what it can do in real time (without having to press "submit"). People here tend to be more generous with people who at least give formatting a try!

Comment: @Theo -ok ,thanks a lot for providing tutorial .

Comment: You may accept this answer.

Comment: @ZAhmed:Can you give other solution.Any idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$f(x)=0$ if $x<1$, $f(x)=2\sinh(x-1)$ and $g(x)=\cosh(x-1)$
The equation$f(x)=g(x)$ gives $x=1+\log \sqrt{3}.$ and $g(x)>f(x), 0 \le x \le 1+\log \sqrt{3}.$
The required area is

$A=\int_{0}^{1} \cosh(x-1) dx+ \int_{1}^{1+\log\sqrt{3}}[\cosh(x-1)-2\sinh(x-1)]dx$

**Edit:** A simpler version

If $x<1$, then $f_<(x)=e^{x-1}-e^{x-1}=0$

If $x>1$,then $f_>(x)=e^{x-1}-e^{1-x}$

$g(x)=\frac{1}{2}[e^{x-1}+e^{1-x}]$

For $x<1$, $g(x)=f(x)\implies g(x)=0$, no solution.

For $x>1$, we get $e^{2(x-1)}=3e^{1-x} \implies e^{2(x-1)}=3 \implies 
x=1+\log \sqrt{3}$

For $x<1$, obviously $g(x)>f(x)$. Also for $1<x <1+\log \sqrt{3}.$

So the area enclosed by $y=f(x), y=g(x)$ and $x=0$, from $x=0$ to $x=1+\log \sqrt{3}=a$ is given by

$A=\int_{0}^1 [g(x)-0] dx+\int_{1}^a [g(x)-f_>(x)]dx$

Comment: Do you really want both $\sinh$ and $\sin$? or is one of those a typo?

Comment: Thanks it should be sinh.

Comment: @ZAhmed-thanks a lot .